# Want to insert data in two tables using one controller file in CakePhp

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to add data in two tables form one controller file when I call function for add data in second one table ..error comes Error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object

Here is my controller file

```
<?php
class CountryController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Country';
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form' );


    // called index function 
    public function index() {
        $this->render();
    }

    // Function for add countries in database
    public function addCountry() {
        if (empty($this->data)) {
            $this->render();
        } else {
        //  $this->cleanUpFields();
            if ($this->Country->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('The Counrty has been saved');
                $this->redirect('/country/index');
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Please correct errors below.');
            }
        }
    }

    public function addCity() {
        $cities = $this->set('country', $this->Country->find('all'));
        $this->set(compact('cities'));
        if(empty($this->data)){
            $this->render();
        } else {
            print_r($this->data);// die();
            if ($this->City->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('The City has been saved');
                $this->redirect('/country/index');
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Please correct errors below.');
            }
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var $uses = array('Main model name' , '2nd model name' .......so on);

Eg:

```
<?php
class CountryController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Country';
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form' );
    // $uses is where you specify which models this controller uses
    var $uses = array('Country', 'City');

    // ... here go your controller actions (methods)

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... am try with that .. and make model file name city.php and also create a table in db named cities but this time come an error Notice (8): Array to string conversion [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php, line 459]

Comment: Please check your input values

Comment: ya its works .. now i was try with own custom function .. now am try with save() its works... thanks alot..!
Can you please let me know where we can write own custom query for db in cakePHp ?

Comment: In your controller can write custom quries like this $this->City->query("SELECT * FROM cities;");

Answer (score 1):

You can use model chaining. I'm assuming a City and Country are related (maybe be an intermediary model State?).

So it would be `$this->Country->City->save()` or `$this->Country->IntermediaryModel->City->save()` depending on your relationships.